# MVC4 dynamically changing master layout page doesn't work on first load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 mobile project that I want to add a desktop (non mobile) page to for some users.

I have added a new desktop master page and assigned my view to use it.

The first time I navigate to the page it renders using jquerymobile which appears to somehow be cached from the previous screen.

If I hit `F5` to `refresh` the page it displays using the assigned desktop masterpage correctly.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Any insight appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure the cause of this but found a work around.

Instead of creating the button to link to the next screen like this:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("ReviewTeamOrders", "Team")" data-theme="b" data-role="button">View Pots Orders</a>
```

I changed it to be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("ReviewTeamOrders", "Team")'" data-theme="b" data-role="button" >View Pots Orders</a>
```

Seems to do the trick!